# What is the cause of the segmentation fault in this program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers

I'm practicing my "code golf" or programming interview-like questions and can't figure out why I'm getting a segmentation fault in the following:

```
#include <iostream>

bool contained ( char * str1, char * str2 )
{
// returns true or false depending on whether the string str1 is contained in str2
    while (str2)
    {
       if (*str1 == *str2)
       {
           char * temp = str2; 
           while (*str1++ == *temp++);
           if (!*str1) return true;
       }
       else 
       {
           ++str2;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

int main () 
{
   char sa [] = "abc"; 
   char sb [] = "rehabc132";
   std::cout << contained(sa, sb); // should print out 1
   return 0;
}
```

Proof: http://codepad.org/5Ff3qTIX

Any ideas why?

Comment: Since the second string is longer, you're running past the end of the first string...

Comment: Also, you probably meant `while (*str2)`?

Comment: `*str1++` is nested in two loops, so eventually you run off the end of that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error 1:** The outer loop shall be `while (*str2)` otherwhise you'll go out of range and risk a segfault.

**Error 2:** The inner loop shall check that none of the string reacehs the end:  `while (*str1 && *temp && *str1++ == *temp++ );`

**Error 3:**  In the inner loop, you loose the beginning of the string you're looking for (str1).  So you should use another temporary pointer.  I'll leave that part as an excercise for you.